# How to retrieve value from a map based on object

Tags: java, android, hashmap

In the code shown here, I am inflating a view and add it to a linearlayout. Each view when clicked should open a particular document related to it. What I am thinking of to achieve this is to add each inflated view to a map as key and the
value of the map will be the document.

My question is, how to add each view to the map as a key and how to retrieve a specific value from the map given the key. I referred to some posts but I do not know how to get the value from the map based on a given key especially
that my key is an object **view**.

Code:

```
private void inflateView(String bez, String ges) {
    LinearLayout linLay = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.versicherungsListeActivity2mod_linLay_meineDocList_container);

    View viewDivider = new View(this);
    viewDivider.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    viewDivider.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));

    LayoutInflater inflator = this.getLayoutInflater();
    View view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.versicherung_docs_row_model, null);//<<<<<< this is the view i want to add to the map as a key

    ImageView imgViewLogo = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.versicherungslisteactivity2_docs_lisvie_row_model_imgVie_logo);
    TextView texVieBez = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.versicherungslisteactivity2_docs_lisvie_row_model_texVie_docBezeichnung);
    TextView texVieExtraItem = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.versicherungslisteactivity2_docs_lisvie_row_model_texVie_addMoreDocs);
    TextView texVieGes = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.versicherungslisteactivity2_docs_lisvie_row_model_texVie_docGesellschaft);
    Button btnMore = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.versicherungslisteactivity2_docs_lisvie_row_model_btn_more);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        imgViewLogo.setImageDrawable(this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.insurance_details_doc, this.getTheme()));
    } else {
        imgViewLogo.setImageDrawable(this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.insurance_details_doc));
    }

    texVieBez.setText(bez);
    texVieGes.setText(bez);
    btnMore.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    linLay.addView(view);

    linLay.addView(viewDivider);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all I'd not recommend using a reference to the `View` as a key for the Map - that could cause a leaked reference and memory issues. Instead assign a tag to the view via `setTag(Object obj)` method. Later on retrieve the document calling map.get(key) in the click listener, where key is the tag you've assigned.

inside `inflateView`:

```
String tag = "Something unique for a key" // can be any Object not necessarily a String
view.setTag(tag);
map.put(tag, referenceToDocument);
view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Object document = map.get(view.getTag());
            // do whatever you like with the document
        }
});
```